# AutoComplete suggestions to editText but to only suggest previously entered words?

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext

So basically I want a user to enter some text into an editText but later on when they come back to that edit text and start typing it suggests the words that they've previously entered. Is there any way do do this? thanks in advance.

It would be similar to an autoComplete email form in your web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Just save all the words the user has entered to a database, file, or to shared prefs, where ever you like and populate the adapter with those words.